# How to iterate multidimensional array in mustache?

Tags: templates, mustache

If have the this multidimensional array :

```
 "arr" : [
  {"code":"glove", "arr1": [{ "value":"fingers"}, {"value":"hands","lastValue":true}]},
  {"code":"coloris", "arr1": [{"value":"Black"}, {"value":"white", "lastValue":true}], "last":true}
]
```

How do you iterate this ?
I have tried this but it seems it does not work as expected

```
{{#arr}}
   {{#arr1}}
            {{value}} - {{code}}
      {{^lastValue}}, {{/lastValue}}
   {{/arr1}}
   {{^last}}, {{/last}}
{{/arr}}
```

Any ideas ? Thanks

The expected result should be :

```
fingers - glove,
hands - glove 
,
Black - coloris,
white - coloris
```

Comment: The braces and brackets don't match up in your first code block. Also, your second code block has `{#arr.size}` and `{/arr.size}`, with single braces, which is not a valid way to write Mustache tags (unless you override the delimiters, but then the other tags should look like that, too). Please correct your code so that your problem is reproducible, otherwise nobody will be able to address your actual problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The curly braces and square brackets in the first code block (the multidimensional array, input data) still don't match up.

Comment: So, which Mustache engine are you using and what result are you getting? When I try your template with Wontache, I get the result you expect but with more whitespace. You can try that here: https://jgonggrijp.gitlab.io/wontache/playground.html.